# Bar filled with value of mic activity level

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, microphone

This is the code of a bar being filled with the values of the mic activity level, the problem is when the bar is raising it starts to fill to the right side as well instead of being only moving to the left side.

This is the code:

```
**micaux** is just the total of mic.activityLevel
**bar** is the borders of the raising bar
**cor2** is the bar that i want to fill

if ( micaux > 0 ) {
         soundbox.text = String(micaux);
         bar.cor2.x +=  mic.activityLevel / 1000;
         bar.cor2.scaleX +=  mic.activityLevel /1000; }
```

I took a printscreen of the app working and what happens:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: IIUC, mic.activityLevel is an absolute value. Shouldn't you then use bar.cor2.x = .... and bar.cor2.scaleX = .... (i.e. '=' instead of '+=')?

Comment: no it's not working, if i do that the bar just freeze....

Comment: I think it happens because you're increasing the scale of the object. You can probably fix that by doing a transformation that scales that object (and maintains the x coordinate), or instead of increasing the scale, try increasing the width of the object. Trace out the value of the x coordinate to confirm.